# How to hide all link that connect to a particular breed in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Greeting,

This is the scenario:
I have 2 breed namely: "dog" and "cat"
Links are established within dog breed only and cat breed only, and temporarily there is no cross linkages.
I am looking for a way to hide dog breed and links that is associated with dog only. I would like to add that the links are not randomly generated, they are known links given to the breed. The purpose of doing it this way is that I am doing a network calculation on each breed individually using `nw:mean-path-length`

In netlogo documentation, I will be using 
`ask dog[ hide-turtle ]` to hide the dog breed. However, I do not know **how to hide link associated with dog only**. And similarly, I will be using  `ask dog[ show-turtle ]` to make dog breed appear again(with the links associated with dog too) and use `ask cat[ hide-turtle ]` for my calculation on the other breed.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ask dogs [ ask my-links [ hide-link ] ]
```

...will hide the dogs' links.

That being said, if you want to perform calculations on a separate part of a network, you will need to use [`nw:set-context`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#set-context): just hiding the turtles and links won't affect the results of primitives like `nw:mean-path-length`.